# What's the directory structure should be for multiple domains under a single user? (apache)

Tags: apache, dns, structure, directory

I have an account on some VPS(friend's apache server with cPanel) and there I have one public_html directory.
We have in there about 5-6 websites:

```
/home/myusername/public_html/domain-1.name/index.php
/home/myusername/public_html/domain-2.name/index.php
```

but I don't like this way, I'd like to orginise it better and be able to separate and isolate some stuff for each website.
So what if I create like that:

```
/home/myusername/websites/domain-1.name/public_html/index.php

/home/myusername/websites/domain-2.name/public_html/index.php and so on
```

Would it be a correct way of structurising web directories? 
And would apache work like that?
Perhaps there are out there some other conventions or common workarounds?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly fine. In fact I'd highly recommend against using the *domain folder* as the document root as typical web application will also contain data that is not publically accessable (e.g. configuration files, management scripts, version control files, etc.)

Personally I prefer the name `htdocs` and I keep my sites under `/srv/http`

For example:

```
/srv/http/user1/domain1/htdocs/
/srv/http/user1/domain2/htdocs/
/srv/http/user1/domain3/htdocs/
/srv/http/user2/domain4/htdocs/
/srv/http/user3/domain5/htdocs/
```

That way you can set the `DocumentRoot` to the `htdocs` directory and put other stuff that is not meant to be delivered by the web server in a different sub directory of the domain directory.

Comment: Thanks bikeshedder! What's the meaning standing behind those namings? srv/ htdocs/?
I'd like to keep everything semantically readable and easy understandable

Comment: Ok I figured out srv - server, htdocs - http documents.  
Regarding to "_highly recommend against using the domain folder as the document root as typical web application will also contain data that is not publically accessable_"  
That was one of the reasons why I want to change current structure.  
And I though this will do:  
`/home/myusername/websites/domain-1.name/public_html/index.php    

/home/myusername/websites/domain-1.name/resources/  
/home/myusername/websites/domain-1.name/config.php  
/home/myusername/websites/domain-1.name/src/  
/home/myusername/websites/domain-1.name/etc/`

Comment: If you are happy with `/home/myusername/websites/domain-1.name` go for it. Everyone does it a little bit different and there is no reason for not using a directory structure that fits your needs best. `/srv/http` and `/var/www` is often used but this is not a requirement at all.

Comment: Sorry man, couldn't figure out how to nicely put the paths. they all become inline.  What I was trying to say, is that ni my understanding **DocumentRoot** is not in **domain-1.name** direcotry, but under and in subdirectory **Public-html**. hope that makes sence

Comment: But I like this way as well `/srv/http/user1/domain1/htdocs/`.   I perhaps will using for our local file/web server. I think `/http/` will clearly divide from local file share directories

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I want just to conclude and to outline the way I went with.
Thanks to @bikeshedder for ideas!

So having a single account(none-root) `/home/myusername/` under linux VPS server, I didn't want to abstract completely from existent directory structure, but at the same time I wanted to create proper environment to isolate and separate clients and their spaces.

**Main goals were:**
    * The new directory structure should help to keep all files and folders in a nice and clear order.
    * Easy to navigate and browse.
    * Each developer or client would have access only to their space.

**The structure:**

```
/home/myusername/http/client-1/domain-1/public_html/index.php
/home/myusername/http/client-1/domain-1/resources/
/home/myusername/http/client-1/domain-1/configuration.php
/home/myusername/http/client-1/domain-2/public_html/index.php
/home/myusername/http/client-1/client's_resource_dir/  

/home/myusername/http/client-2/domain-3/public_html/index.php
/home/myusername/http/client-2/domain-3/subdomain/public_html/index.php
```

**As result:**
 * We have isolated client's space and isolated domain space. That makes enough room for any type of web projects.
 * Files and dirs are not mixed up with other projects, domains and clients anymore.
 * For subdomain paths it can be
    - as subdirectories `/domain-3.name/subdomain/public_html/`
    - or additional subdomain directory `/subdomain.domain-3.name/public_html/`depending on requirements or size of subdomain website.
 * **Public_html** is going to be a **DocumentRoot** for each website.

I did not go for `srv/` and `var/www` dirs, cuz to me it sounds like server in the server and also I don't feel variable data `var/` in current setup falls under web stuff.
Though it may make sense for our coming soon local web/file sharing server

But here now I have another question:
How would I specify new path to be a default one for cPanel? and only for my user?
Cuz now there is going to be multiple **DocumentRoot** directories in one user space.
Is that possible by Apache design?
I better create new question :) And then will edit my question with answer

Any suggestion welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Normally go with this once hosting from 5-30++ sites, depending on complexity of content, traffic, perceived future migration strategies to more dedicated virtual or bare metal servers/instances.

```
/<node-serial-or-hostname-or-domain>/<@|subdomain|www|others>/index.<html|php|jsp|aspx|what-not>
/<node-serial-or-hostname-or-domain>/<@|subdomain|www|others>/assets/...

/<node-serial-or-hostname-or-domain>/<@|subdomain|www|others>/index.<html|php|jsp|aspx|what-not>
/<node-serial-or-hostname-or-domain>/<@|subdomain|www|others>/assets/...

/<node-serial-or-hostname-or-domain>/<@|subdomain|www|others>/index.<html|php|jsp|aspx|what-not>
/<node-serial-or-hostname-or-domain>/<@|subdomain|www|others>/assets/...

/<node-serial-or-hostname-or-domain>/<@|subdomain|www|others>/index.<html|php|jsp|aspx|what-not>
/<node-serial-or-hostname-or-domain>/<@|subdomain|www|others>/assets/...

/<node-serial-or-hostname-or-domain>/<@|subdomain|www|others>/index.<html|php|jsp|aspx|what-not>
/<node-serial-or-hostname-or-domain>/<@|subdomain|www|others>/assets/...
```